# Users with duplicate logins in ASP.Net's Sql MembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net-membership

We have an ASP.NET (well, WCF) application that uses the SqlMembershipProvider to authenticate its users. They log in using their username and password.

However, I'd like to group these users by customer, so that every customer can have its own "admin" or "Demo" user. Consequently, they'd log in using their customer id, username, and password.

I have not found a decent way to this with the MembershipProvider yet. Have I missed something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to go beyond the functionality offered by the standard asp.net membership provider. It doesn't have those capabilities. The asp.net membership and role system is extremely simple.

One option would be to use Active Directory (possible Active Directory Application Mode to keep things separate and avoid licensing). In AD you have much more possibilities to group users into different containers and delegate control over users in a specific container to an "admin" user.